# A created Form is invisible

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a very simple Form. When I call Show() on it, it is not displayed.

1. It is in the taskbar and resting on it in the taskbar displays the window in the taskbar popup.
2. The Location is 0, 0 (to make it easy to find).
3. The Size is 128, 98 so it has a size.
4. If I create any other Form and the call Form.Show() on it at the same place - it works.

This is driving me nuts. Any ideas?

**update:** reduced sample to the key code (for others that make this mistake):

```
    namespace AutoTagCore.net.windward.autotag.controls.start_here
    {
        partial class TemplatePopUp
        {

            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
...
                this.Opacity = 0D;
...
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have some form of license call that needs to be made for the `DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl()` before any use of it is made.

For XCeed Components you must place the call for Xceed.Grid.Licenser.LicenseKey in your main program startup before you attempt to use them.. It that possible with your DevExpress stuff?

Found it:

It's your Opacity.

you have

```
this.Opacity = 0D;
```

should be

```
this.Opacity = 1D;
```

Comment: Yes but that has been called. This is deep inside our code where we have several forms displaying numerous DevExpress controls.

Comment: I just changed it to no DevExpress controls - Form & Label instead - same problem.

Comment: That's it - No idea how/why - I must have clicked something wrong in the designer. So yes, the window is there, but 100% transparent.